# Can I install NodeJS when MeteorJS already installed on the same computer? Does it damage Meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have MeteorJS already installed on my win8.1 and I want to install NodeJS to be able to install Ghost (blogging platform) on my pc to try it and play with it…
Is it possible? does it gonna effect meteor operations? how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding already answered stuff

> Meteor is to Node as Rails is to Ruby." It's a large, opinionated framework that uses Node on the server. Node itself is just a low-level framework providing functions for sending and receiving HTTP requests and performing other I/O.
>   [node vs meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461411/node-js-vs-meteor-js-whats-the-difference)

we can run multiple node version/instances in a single system.

[Running multiple nodeJs instances in a single system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455290/install-different-versions-of-nodejs)

You will not face any issue.

Comment: The point that I don't get is that I will be installing nodeJs when it's already installed! But can't be used! So how reinstalling it is not going to affect the one already installed?

Comment: this will help you. You can have multiple version/instance of node running in same system. [running multiple node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455290/install-different-versions-of-nodejs)

Comment: ok thank you, please add the link in the comment above to your answer so I mark it as the accepted answer