# What's the relationship between meteor and node?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Is meteor just a large framework sitting on top of node or it's another platform just as node?

If it's a framework, why it comes with its own package manager: Atmosphere?

Can I integrate other npm packages easily in an meteor application?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered on this thread.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461411/node-js-vs-meteor-js-whats-the-difference

Comment: @DocHolliday, thanks for pointing out another relevant question. But it doesn't answer the 2nd and 3rd question I asked.

Comment: Atmosphere is to some extent historical, but there are still many functional packages there which work well. Moving forward you should use npm packages. Install the packages using npm install (or meteor npm install...) and then refer to them with import... Style sheets can be imported the same way

Comment: All of your questions are answered in detail in the documentation of meteor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Meteor is to Node as Rails is to Ruby. -- [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461411/node-js-vs-meteor-js-whats-the-difference)
2. Atmosphere is a go-to place for all things meteor, from a package
   perspective.
3. Try installing other [npm packages](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-npm-packages/) via:

   `meteor npm install --save [package name]` and
   `meteor npm install`